# The existence of the derivative of a Banach space valued function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, frechet-derivative

In Evans' *Partial Differential Equations* $\S 7.1$, there is a motivation for definition of weak solution.

> \begin{align*} 
> (1) \begin{cases} u_t + Lu = f \ &\text{in} \ U_T\\
>  u = 0 \ &\text{on} \ \partial U \times [0,T]\\
> u = g \ &\text{on} \ U \times \{ t = 0 \}  \end{cases}.
> \end{align*}

> $\textbf{Motivation for definition of weak solution.}$ To make plausible the following definition of weak solution, let us first temporarily suppose that $u = u(x,t)$ is in fact a smooth solution in parabolic setting of our problem $(1)$. We now switch our viewpoint, by associating with $u$ a mapping

> $$\textbf{u}: [0,T] \longrightarrow H^1_0(U)$$

> defined by

> $$[\textbf{u}(t)](x) := u(x,t) \ (x \in U, 0 \leq t \leq T).$$

> In other words, we are going consider $u$ not as a function of $x$ and $t$ together, but rather as a mapping  $\textbf{u}$ of $t$  into the space $H^1_0(U)$ of functions of $x$. This point of view will greatly clarify the following presentation.

> Returning to the problem $(1)$, let us similary define

> $$\textbf{f}: [0,T] \longrightarrow L^2(U)$$

> by

> $$[\textbf{f}(t)](x) := f(x,t) \ (x \in U, 0 \leq t \leq T).$$

> Then if we fix a function $v \in H^1_0(U)$, we can multiply the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + Lu = f$ by $v$ and integrate by parts, to find

> $$ (9)\ (\textbf{u}',v) + B[\textbf{u},v;t] = (\textbf{f},v) \ \left( ' = \frac{d}{dt} \right)$$

> for each $0 \leq t \leq T$, the pairing $(,)$ denoting the inner product of $L^2(U)$.

If we multiply the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + Lu = f$ by $v \in H^1_0(U)$, then we would get $(u_t,v) + B[\textbf{u},v;t] = (\textbf{f},v)$. However, the first term in (9) is $(\textbf{u}',v)$ instead of $(u_t,v)$.

As far as I know, $\textbf{u}' = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\textbf{u}(t+h) - \textbf{u}(t)}{h}$ in $H^1_0(U)$, in other words, $ \Big\Vert \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\textbf{u}(t+h) - \textbf{u}(t)}{h} - \textbf{u}' \Big\Vert_{H^1_0(U)} \to 0$. On the other hands, $u_t = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{u(t+h,x) - u(t)}{h}$ and the limit is pointwise.

So, I am wondering how to show that $\textbf{u}'$ exists from the existence of $u_t$ and also $\textbf{u}'$ is equal to $u_t$. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the book, $\mathbf{u}'$ isn't the classical derivative as defined in your post.

As defined in Section 5.9.2 (*Spaces involving time*), $\mathbf{u}'$ stands for the "weak" derivative of $\mathbf{u}$, that is, a function $\mathbf{v}$ such that
$$\int_0^T \varphi'(t)\mathbf{u}(t)\;dt=-\int_0^T \varphi(t)\mathbf{v}(t)\;dt,\quad\forall \ \varphi\in C_c^\infty(0,T).$$
Since $\mathbf{v}=u_t$ satisfies the above equality, we have $\mathbf{u}'=u_t$ in the weak sence (which is the book's claim).